# sending Multi Values for one variable in PHP URL?

Tags: javascript, php

I want some one to assist me in this issue, I have code

```
$("#test").jCombo("{!! url('test/comboselect?filter=pos:po_code:po_code&limit=WHERE:done_by:!=:1') !!}",
```

Related to this function,

```
function getComboselect( Request $request)
{

if($request->ajax() == true && \Auth::check() == true)
{
    $param = explode(':',$request->input('filter'));
    $parent = (!is_null($request->input('parent')) ? $request->input('parent') : null);
    $limit = (!is_null($request->input('limit')) ? $request->input('limit') : null);
    $rows = $this->model->getComboselect($param,$limit,$parent);
    $items = array();

    $fields = explode("|",$param[2]);

    foreach($rows as $row) 
    {
        $value = "";
        foreach($fields as $item=>$val)
        {
            if($val != "") $value .= $row->{$val}." ";
        }
        $items[] = array($row->{$param['1']} , $value);     

    }

    return json_encode($items);     
} else {
    return json_encode(array('OMG'=>" Ops .. Cant access the page !"));
}   
}
```

I need way to send many values for variable limit and receive in that function like this;

```
 $("#test").jCombo("{!! url('test/comboselect?filter=pos:po_code:po_code&limit=WHERE:done_by:!=:1&limit=WHERE:entry_by:=:1') !!}",
```

Comment: How about creating an array for your `limit` GET var ? Something like `&limit[]=WHERE:done_by:!=:1&limit[]=WHERE:entry_by:=:1` ?

Comment: What's your actual issue? _"related to this function"_ how? What does your function do? Where does it fail? What is the expected output? What's the current output? Start by reading these guides: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update your question.

Comment: This function call values from DB tables depending on so many parameters
like you are calling from The DB with my SQL "Select * from test where done_by != 1, entry_by = 1"
something like that.

Answer (score 1):

URL parameters can represent an array, so instead of

```
limit=WHERE:done_by:!=:1&limit=WHERE:entry_by:=:1
```

you can do

```
limit[]=WHERE:done_by:!=:1&limit[]=WHERE:entry_by:=:1
```

The `[]` cause PHP to parse them into one array of strings.  So in your PHP code you can

```
$limit = null;
if (!empty($request->input('limit'))) {
    $limit = $request->input('limit');
    if (is_array($limit) {
        // $limit[0] = WHERE:done_by:!=:1
        // $limit[1] = WHERE:entry_by:=:1
        //
    }
}
```